# How do I control the centering of JButton HTML text in NetBeans?

Tags: java, html, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to put a two-line piece of text on a JButton; e.g.

```
+----------+
|  READER  |
|   STOP   |
+----------+
```

But I'm having trouble getting it centered on the button.  I go to the Property editor for the JButton, and enter `<html><center>READER<br>STOP` for the **text** property.  This causes the two words to be centered with respect to each other, but together they still appear to be shifted toward the right side of the face of the button, as in:

```
+----------+
|    READER|
|     STOP |
+----------+
```

There are also Horizontal & Vertical Alignment & Text Position properties, which I've set all to CENTER, but this doesn't have any effect that I can see.

EDIT: here is an illustration of how it is laid out when I omit `<center>` entirely, in case anyone is confused by my description that "READER and STOP are left-justified w/respect to each other, but right-justified on the button":

```
+----------+
|    READER|
|    STOP  |
+----------+
```

EDIT: here is the code generated by NetBeans:

```
    readerStopButton_.setBackground(javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("Button.light"));
    readerStopButton_.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Geneva", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    readerStopButton_.setText("<html><center>READER<br>STOP</center></html>\n");
    readerStopButton_.setToolTipText("<html><b>Stop</b> button is currently inactive.  ");
    readerStopButton_.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    readerStopButton_.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            readerStopButton_ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    operationButtons_.add(readerStopButton_);
```

EDIT: Here's a screen capture of how the button looks to me.  There is a lot I don't know about doing layouts, so it's quite possible I'm omitting some crucial info.  But basically I'm letting NetBeans do all the work, except for providing the HTML text.

EDIT: Putting up a replacement screen shot that shows all buttons.  Note that the ones that don't use HTML (the single-word ones) are correctly aligned, while the two that do use HTML are messed up.

[image: better view of problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason is you limited the size of the button, by default there is a margin for button, you can remove the margin as follows:

```
readerStopButton_.setMargin(new Insets(0,-30, 0,-30));
```

[image]

```
package swing;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class HTMLTextTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JPanel operationButtons_ = new JPanel();

        JButton readerStopButton_ = new JButton();
        readerStopButton_.setBackground(javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("Button.light"));
        readerStopButton_.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Geneva", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        readerStopButton_.setText("<html><center>READER<br>STOP</center></html>\n");
        readerStopButton_.setToolTipText("<html><b>Stop</b> button is currently inactive.  ");
        readerStopButton_.setMargin(new Insets(0,-30, 0,-30));
        readerStopButton_.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(66, 40));
        operationButtons_.add(readerStopButton_);

        readerStopButton_ = new JButton();
        readerStopButton_.setBackground(javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("Button.light"));
        readerStopButton_.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Geneva", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        readerStopButton_.setText("<html><center>READER<br>STOP</center></html>\n");
        readerStopButton_.setToolTipText("<html><b>Stop</b> button is currently inactive.  ");
        System.out.println(readerStopButton_.getPreferredSize());
        readerStopButton_.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(66, 40));
        operationButtons_.add(readerStopButton_);

        operationButtons_.add(new JButton("yCoder.com"));

        frame.add(operationButtons_);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget the closing tag:

```
JButton button = new JButton("<html><center>READER<br>STOP</center></html>");
```

See also [*How to Use HTML in Swing Components*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

Addendum: I have shamelessly cloned @mre's [correct HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963021/how-do-i-control-the-centering-of-jbutton-html-text-in-netbeans/6964178#6964178) above to produce the following image:

[image]

Comment: Hm, no, that's not it, I don't think.  It *does* respect the `<center>` tag (and I've also tried closing that one) -- if I omit `<center>`, READER and STOP become left-justified with respect to each other, but still somewhat right-justified on the button.  (Edit: the link you mentioned *does* show centering, but not within NetBeans "form", which I'm highly dependent upon right now and not real sure how I can do tweaks.

Comment: I've updated my errant HTML to comport with @mre's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963021/how-do-i-control-the-centering-of-jbutton-html-text-in-netbeans/6964178#6964178), to which I would defer.

Comment: I've updated question with screen shot of what I'm seeing.  FWIW, I'm using Lion.  Your "stoplights" look too large to be Lion, yes?

Comment: Yes, Leopard. What do you see with @mre's sscce?

Comment: I see exactly what you posted above.  Guess I'll copy my code into a non-NetBeans editor and start removing things one at a time, unless you can suggest a better idea.

Comment: Well, that narrows it down to something specified to (or generated by) the GUI editor. I'm not sure migrating will change that. BTW, I think there was a typo in the tooltip's HTML.

Comment: Those buttons are in a grid layout.  I accidentally moved one out of the grid, and its text problem corrected itself.  I guess it's as good a time as any to revisit the whole sordid subject of layout, since my ineptitude with it continues to burn me.  I'll have to leave this problem aside for now, but will return to it once I have a clear notion why (apparently) the Grid layout is influencing text alignment in that manner.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you're talking about. I used the code you've included and it works just fine.

---

```
public final class HTMLTextButtonDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();             
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton readerStopButton_ = new JButton();
        readerStopButton_.setFocusPainted(false);
        readerStopButton_.setBackground(UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("Button.light"));
        readerStopButton_.setFont(new Font("Geneva", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        readerStopButton_.setText("<html><center>READER<br>STOP</center></html>\n");
        readerStopButton_.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        frame.add(readerStopButton_);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

The HTML text is center justified. It's hard to imagine that you're seeing something different.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/); for reference, I see the expected result on `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`.

Comment: Of course my code is embedded into hundreds of lines of NetBeans-generated source, which may well be where the problem really lies.  I updated original question to include screen capture of button as I see it.

Comment: OH god you really need to use HTML just to align the text to center? Java developers you are missing out so much.